# Get input element in selected rows

Tags: jquery

I have table like this :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tbody id="itemlist">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="item[code][]" value="1">Fotocopy</td>
            <td><input type="number" class="qty" name="item[qty][]" value="2"></td>
            <td><input type="number" class="price" name="item[price][]" value="200"></td>
            <td><p class="total">400</p></td>
            <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="hapus">Hapus</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="item[code][]" value="1">Download</td>
            <td><input type="number" class="qty" name="item[qty][]" value="2"></td>
            <td><input type="number" class="price" name="item[price][]" value="2000"></td>
            <td><p class="total">4000</p></td>
            <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="hapus">Hapus</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How to get all inputs element on selected rows, If I change qty field on second rows ?

```
$(document).on('keypress','input.qty', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode==13){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('td').find("input.qty").each(function(index) {
                var x = this.value;
                var price = $(this).closest('tr td').find("input.price").val() ;
                var qty = $("input.qty").val() ;
                var total = price * qty;
                console.log(price);
                //$("p.total").html(total);
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
```

I have created a Fiddle for [this HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/eamptjdt/)

It would be really helpful if some one can give me some idea

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you want to handle keyboard event or mouse event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using on keypress use on change function. 
Here the code which maybe useful to you.

```
 $('.qty').on('change',function(){

  var price = $(this).parents('tr').find(".price").val() ;

     var qty = ($(this).val());

    var total = price * qty;

   $(this).parents('tr').find(".total").text(total);
  });
```

- Help :)

Comment: you can compressed `.parent().parent()` by `.parents("tr")`

Comment: Yes we can compress it , Nice add Atikur.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Help, it works

I do little change of your code :

```
$(document).on('blur','.qty',function(){
  var price = $(this).parents('tr').find(".price").val() ;
  var qty = ($(this).val());
  var total = price * qty;
  $(this).parents('tr').find(".total").html(total);
});
```